# How to implement click events on Microsoft Chart Control on ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, charts, mschart

MSChart Control is originally a webforms control. The typical strategy for including this control on ASP.NET MVC is to create the chart in the controller then render it as an image to the view. Here's an [example of how it's actually done](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125230/ASP-NET-MVC-Chart-Control).

My concern is then since the chart itself is rendered as an image, you are not able to bind any chart-related events to it with normal methods, such as mouse hover on a point to show tooltip or click event on a bar. Would something like this possible on MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  Not with the MSChart control. Because like webforms, everything gets sent to the browser and is rendered there.  The chart is just an image.

A lot of people use HighCharts.   I've used Google charts.